# Density Based Clustering with Representatives

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki, mean-shift

I'm looking for a method to perform density based clustering. The resulting clusters should have a representative unlike `DBSCAN`. 
`Mean-Shift` seems to fit those needs but doesn't scale enough for my needs. I have looked into some subspace clustering algorithms and only found `CLIQUE` using representatives, but this part is not implemented in **Elki**.

Comment: Why don't you add the "missing" functionality then?

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comments on the previous iteration of your question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720959/dbscan-java-library-with-corepoints

Density-based clustering does **not assume there is a center or representative**.

Consider the following example [image from Wikipedia user Chire](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DBSCAN-density-data.svg) (BY-CC-SA 3.0):

[image]

**Which object should be the representative of the red cluster?**

Density-based clustering is about finding "arbitrarily shaped" clusters. These do not have a meaningful single representative object. They are not meant to "compress" your data - this is not a [vector quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_quantization) method, but *structure discovery*. But it is the nature of such complex structure that it cannot be reduced to a single representative. **The proper representation of such a cluster is the set of all points in the cluster.** For geometric understanding in 2D, you can also compute convex hulls, for example, to get an area as in that picture.

Choosing representative objects is a different task. This is not needed for discovering this kind of structure, and thus these algorithms do not compute representative objects - it would waste CPU.

Answer (score 2):

You could choose the object with the highest density as representative of the cluster.

It is a fairly easy modification to DBSCAN to store the neighbor count of every object.

But as Anony-Mousse mentioned, the object may nevertheless be a rather bad choice. Density-based clustering is not designed to yield representative objects.

You could try AffinityPropagation, but it will also not scale very well.